# Deadlock with asynchronous non-blocking MPI

Tags: mpi

I am trying to figure out why the following code snipped deadlocks occasionally. Running on `2` processes, each process starts asynchronous sends and receives with the other process. However, the number of invocations on the two processes is different (`num_iters`). To match outstanding messages, at the end of the for-loop, each process checks if a send or receive is in progress, and if not, initiates a matching message. Finally, each process waits on the matched communication. Why does the code occasionally deadlock? (It's been tested with both OpenMPI and MPICH)

```
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int procs;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs);
  if (procs != 2) {
    std::cout << "Runs with 2 processes!";
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  int buffer_size = 10;
  std::vector<double> snd_buffer(buffer_size, 4.2);
  std::vector<double> rcv_buffer(buffer_size, 0);

  MPI_Request snd_req = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
  int snd_flag;

  MPI_Request rcv_req = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
  int rcv_flag;

  // Asynchronously spam messages
  int comm_rank = (rank + 1) % 2;
  int num_iters = (rank == 0) ? 10 : 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; ++i) {
    MPI_Test(&snd_req, &snd_flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if (snd_flag != 0) {
      MPI_Issend(snd_buffer.data(), buffer_size, MPI_INT, comm_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &snd_req);
    }

    MPI_Test(&rcv_req, &rcv_flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if (rcv_flag != 0) {
      MPI_Irecv(rcv_buffer.data(), buffer_size, MPI_INT, comm_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rcv_req);
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50)); // simulate work
  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // Match outstanding messages
  MPI_Test(&snd_req, &snd_flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  if (snd_flag != 0) {
    MPI_Issend(snd_buffer.data(), buffer_size, MPI_INT, comm_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &snd_req);
  }

  MPI_Test(&rcv_req, &rcv_flag, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  if (rcv_flag != 0) {
    MPI_Irecv(rcv_buffer.data(), buffer_size, MPI_INT, comm_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rcv_req);
  }

  MPI_Wait(&rcv_req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Wait(&snd_req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: I would expect your problem is here 'Finally, each process waits on the matched communication'. Someone is waiting without getting a answer/match, for some reason which results in both are waiting for a answer/match because one is allready blocked and can't answer/match.

Comment: Yes, but how would that happen? I don't see how a request is left non-matched in the code above. Everything is asynchronous up to the MPI_Wait calls.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? Plus, at the moment I don't see how this could ever work. You are sending 10 things with thread 0 to thread 1, but thread 1 expects 20 things. Plus, you are sending 20 things to thread 0, but it expects only 10 things...

Comment: The code should work because the messages are matched... even if the loop iterates `20` times on one processor and `10` on the other. Since new messages are spawned only when a message is received/sent, there shouldn't be a problem. This could be easily verified if one increments counters under the `if()` statements and prints them... the number of messages exchanged is close to 10 usually. Occasionally there will be a difference between sent and received of more than 1 which causes a deadlock and which I can't explain.

Comment: @TeodorNikolov again, what are you trying to achieve? Furthermore, you gave the answer yourself. The number of messages isn't matched correctly. Why? I'm not sure! Because you are using asynchronous functions its hard to tell... The processes could do anything at any time, there is no real causality there... Plus, please explain why the code after `// Match outstanding messages` only has one `send` and `recv` and doesn't use a loop instead.

Comment: @jan.sende I am trying to emulate one-sided communication using the standard non-blocking MPI API. In principle, I'd be perfectly content with cancelling the outstanding communications instead of matching them, however, I still end up in a deadlock if I do that. Moreover, I read that cancelling send operations is "evil" and not well supported. 

The whole point of the question is to understand why the deadlock occurs.... the reason I am using a single send and recv is that I expect at most one outstanding request for communication on each side at the end of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what `MPI_Test` does and what it does not. It does **not** check if there is an outstanding (i.e. pending incoming) message. (You can use `MPI_IProbe`&`MPI_Test` to do that, but it won't really help you). Instead `MPI_Test` does **check if a local operation is completed**. This sort-of works because `MPI_Test` on a null request handle does set the flag to true.

Also note that the synchronous mode (`MPI_Issend`) does not guarantee that the receive is completed, only that the receive is posted.

In one iteration you can complete the send but not yet the receive or the other way around. So there is just no invariant about the symmetry of posted requests that could guarantee deadlock freedom. The actual interaction towards the deadlock is a bit complicated to follow, but you can quite easily add some output to look at what's happening.

The usual way to handle situations with mutually unknown number of messages is to send a specifically marked message indicating that this was the last message (i.e. the loop completed). You can use either data within the message or a special tag. There is a guarantee of non-overtaking messages between the same communication partners that helps you with that.

Comment: What you said is correct but I still fail to see why the code deadlocks. I've added counters to indicate how many calls to `MPI_Issend` and `MPI_Irecv` are made. I do see that, occasionally, a process has two outstanding `MPI_Irecv` (i.e. not matched by `MPI_Issend`), whereas I'd expect at most one oustanding `MPI_Irecv` and that is when the deadlock occurs.... but why would that happen?

Comment: @Zulan Thanks! You put into words what I couldn't do... @ Teodor You are currently sending messages more or less as fast as you can. However there is no check if the message was received by anyone. It is only checked if it was send. Therefore there is no guarantee of messages being matched between the processes. It solely depends on the how fast the processes are. In your code they are roughly the same, so it works most of the time. Try making one slower for some of the iterations, then it should fail more often.

Comment: @TeodorNikolov it seems like you want to provide a variable length communication from one point to another. Either do as @ Zulan suggested and use an EOF message, or send the length of the message before sending the content. Furthermore I would recommend reading on the `isend` and `irecv` [functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Plus, have a look [here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/dynamic-receiving-with-mpi-probe-and-mpi-status/) and [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/mpi/mpi-tutorial-5-asynchronous-communication/)